# JavaScript MediaSource Example

Tags: javascript, media-source

I'm trying to create video player using MediaSource , but I can't make it play while buffering new data. I have this code that downloads the full data then plays it.

```
var vidElement = document.querySelector('video');
if (window.MediaSource) {
  var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
  vidElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
  mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', sourceOpen);
} else {
  console.log("The Media Source Extensions API is not supported.")
}

function sourceOpen(e) {
  URL.revokeObjectURL(vidElement.src);
  var mime = 'video/webm; codecs="opus, vp09.00.10.08"';
  var mediaSource = e.target;
  var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mime);
  var videoUrl = 'droid.webm';
  fetch(videoUrl)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.arrayBuffer();
    })
    .then(function(arrayBuffer) {
      sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', function(e) {
        if (!sourceBuffer.updating && mediaSource.readyState === 'open') {
          mediaSource.endOfStream();
        }
      });
      sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(arrayBuffer);
    });
}
```

This code is not working on the local host. I get the MediaSource closed and this line never gets called

```
mediaSource.endOfStream();
```

1. Can any one tell me why the state is closed, please?
2. Any help about creating player like YouTube or any open source.

and by the way I tried a lot of codes and sources for 2 days now, and it's always the MediaSource giving me errors like the source removed, or not linked.

Comment: Help us out and tell us **what errors** you're seeing.

Comment: `sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', function(e) {
        if (!sourceBuffer.updating && mediaSource.readyState === 'open') {
          mediaSource.endOfStream();
        }
      });` 
this part , i always get mediaSource.readyState === 'close'

Comment: Maybe a fetch request issue? I would suggest always using a catch on your fetches `fetch().then().catch(error => console.log(error))`

Answer (score -2):

For starters, on your first line you have a collection...

```
var V=document.querySelector('video');
```

Shouldn't that be...

```
var V=document.querySelector('video')[0];
```

Before you start operating on it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No, that's not correct. That line seems fine.